# ASP.NET MVC How to specify which folder the View pages reside in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces

by default the ASP.NET MVC engine searches the following folders for View pages:

- /Views/**{Controller_Name}**/{Action}.aspx
- /Views/**Shared**/{Action}.aspx

*However I want to put some of my View pages like this:*

- /Views/**{Namespace}/{Controller_Name}**/{Action}.aspx

***How can I let the engine look for this?***

Comment: sorry for rollback, but it really needs to show like this :-)

Comment: i fixed the category too sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a class derived from IViewEngine interface and register this class in Aplication_Start event in Global.asax.cs
Check this [link text](https://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2008/09/17/the-mvc-platform-view-engines/), but there are some differences with 1.0

Comment: Actually, i've read it a bit and I noticed the VirtualPathProviderViewEngine class. That's what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 77):

You can return view placed in custom sub-folders, from controller action by, giving out full view path in return statement,

ex.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View("~/Views/ProEnhance/Employee/Create.cshtml");
}
```

here,

ProEnhance - user defined folder

Employee   - Controller Name

Create     - action Name

Comment: it is possible to do something like this ?
´View.defaultLocation = "("~/Views/ProEnhance/");
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}´
?

Comment: Any developer, who could answer @Muflix 's question, The above answer (Ofigen's answer) posted does not answer the question properly. I am still in search for this question, too.