# How to create an admin folder for all admin related controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4, I created an admin folder and my controller actions are referencing the views in the admin folder like:

```
   /controllers/admin/UserController.cs
```

My views are here:

```
/views/admin/users/index.cshtml
```

My controller action looks like:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View("~/Views/Admin/Users/Index.cshtml");
 }
```

How can I now setup the routes for all my admin controllers so that the URL has the 'Admin' folder in the URL:

```
http://localhost/admin/user/index
```

Note: MVC 4 does not have "areas".

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4372800/881798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is Areas.

[Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) allows you to logically group related code. you can think of it as a sub mvc app with controllers & views inside your mvc app.

You may simply create an area called "Admin". You will be able to create controllers & views inside that. When you create the area, Visual studio will automatically add the route definition for this area which will include the area name (`Admin`) in the route. Inside the area (`~/Areas/Admin`) you will be able to see a class called "`AdminAreaRegistration.cs`" where the route definition for this area is defined.

Comment: MVC4 doesn't have areas does it?

Comment: MVC4 *does* have areas, they were introduced in mvc 2.

Comment: Travis is correct. Just do a google search https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net%20mvc%20areas%20mvc%204