# How to merge two separate web layers ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

[image]

Hello everyone, I wish you a healthy day.

I have two different MVC projects, I want my project to run under path `localhost:5001/admin/` and the other project to run under `localhost:5001/member/` path. I want to start both projects within the same main function.

I don't want the two projects getting mixed up due to a large number of controllers and views.

I ran it under the Areas folder, however, because the project is very large, I noticed that the files were mixed with each other, so I want to run it in two different layers, but in the same solution.

Some hosting companies do not allow for two separate web tiers, so I want to combine two different web tiers in one project.

Comment: AFAIK You can't do this with kestrel web server.  The only way I know this could work is if you used IIS Express and set each web project as a [virtual directory](https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2014/01/how-to-create-a-virtual-directory-in-iis-express).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm wondering if I can solve this with code because as if I am creating layer instead of creating area, how can I create it like an area by layering.

Comment: @ErikPhilips What I mean to you is, how can I use my controllers and views from a different layer?

Comment: Does this help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @AdithSukumar I tried this. Thanks a lot for your valuable comment.
But I'm looking for a better way, I don't want to need any code changes when I separate the layers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372548/setting-an-alternate-controller-folder-location-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @ErikPhilips This just allows me to use controller from another layer, I want to use both controller and views from another layer.