# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Can't rename the Views folder to another name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was a Java MVC programmer and now I work with .NET, I'm trying to rename the views folder like that:

```
Views/Home/Page1.cshtml
```

to

```
AnotherName/Home/Page1.cshtml
```

In Java I can do, can I do that in ASP.NET?

I don't want rename subfolders in view.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Other developers won't understand what's going on if they have to maintain or use your code. If you still want to though, there are ways to specify where asp.net will search for views.

Comment: Thanks @Mike C
Do you Know how can I do that?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1934303.aspx?rename+default+view+folder+in+asp+net+mvc+4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799838/asp-net-mvc-how-to-specify-which-folder-the-view-pages-reside-in -- might be a good start

Comment: @Mike C, I see your suggest yesterday, but this work for me [link](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/09/11/aspnetmvc4-application-structure-by-features-move-views-by-area/) I will try to use your link im my studies [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc?lq=1). Thank you again.