# HTTP Error 404.0 after renaming folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express, iis-8

I have renamed physical folder name of project files.Also changed its references in appropriate location..After building all successfully it is showing error as in snapshot.How to solve this issue?Are their any other configurations need to be change if we change folder name?[image]

Comment: which folders do you rename?

Comment: The folder which contains controlllers,views etc...Even dubug doesnt go in Global.asax file

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc?lq=1

Comment: and this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799838/asp-net-mvc-how-to-specify-which-folder-the-view-pages-reside-in

Comment: Its references in appropriate location? What are they? Show them and we can point out what you missed.

Comment: Didnt get what exactly you want